# Combine multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
set @col = 'test'; select @col;
```

And use in the `mysql_query` PHP function. How can I do that so it should return 'test' (result of second query)?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query doesn't support multiple queries. You need to use the [Mysqli](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine two become one like

```
select if (@col is null, @col:='test', @col);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a,b,c,d from table1 where a=2

union all

select a,b,c,d from table1 where a=3;
```